# R: Execute a certain function based on position of a minimum in a matrix

Tags: r, function, matrix

I have 4 functions `func1(x), ..., func4(x)` and a matrix `M` of size 2x2. Now I want to compute a certain function value (say `x=1`) depending on the position of the minimum value in `M`.
If the minimum value of `M` is  `M[1,1]`, I want to get `func1(1)`.
If the minimum value of `M` is  `M[2,1]`, I want to get `func2(1)`.
If the minimum value of `M` is  `M[1,2]`, I want to get `func3(1)`.
If the minimum value of `M` is  `M[2,2]`, I want to get `func4(1)`.

Is this somehow possible in R without long ifelse-clauses?

Comment: Please review [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some possibilities:

**1) indexing** If `M` is your matrix -- be sure it is a matrix and not a data.frame -- then:

```
func <- list(func1, func2, func3, func4)[[which.min(M)]]
func(1)
```

**2) switch** Another possibility is:

```
func <- switch(which.min(M), func1, func2, func3, func4)
func(1)
```

**3) paste** If the functions are named as in the question then we can construct the function name dynamically and call it:

```
func_name <- paste0("func", which.min(M))
func <- match.fun(func_name)
func(1)
```

**3a)** or

```
func_name <- paste0("func", which.min(M))
do.call(func_name, list(1))
```